# What is org.apache.log4j.spi.NOPLogger equivalent in log4j2?

Tags: log4j2

I am upgrading the log4j library in the code base from log4j1 to log4j2 and there are references to NOPLogger, but in log4j2 library there is no similar logger available. Has anyone found an alternative? I am not looking to use slfj or any other logging library.

Answer (score 0):

```
org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger logger = (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger) LogManager.getLogger("NoOpLogger");
logger.setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

This will work until the next reconfiguration at which time it will get its log level from the new configuration. As an alternative you can do:

```
Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("NoOpLogger");
```

and then configure

```
<Logger name="NoOpLogger" level="OFF" additivity="false"/>
```

Comment: Would I need to import jul jar to use this as seems like NoOpLogger is present in org.apache.logging.log4j.jul package? https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-jul/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/jul/NoOpLogger.html

Comment: Not for what I proposed. You only need the jul module if you have something using that api